# Provisioning Profiles Not Found

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin

I Have Problem when Publish my APP ios by xamarin studio showing masseage

'No Installed Provisioning Profiles match the Installed IOS Code signing keys'

and when i to to Xcode> reference > Acount

I dont found this Provisioning Profiles show like below image : 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You will have to Log into the [Apple Developer Member Center](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?&appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2F%2Fmembercenter%2Findex.action) and goto section **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles**.

There, you'll perform these steps:

1. Create a development/distribution certificate (you've already done this in XCode)
2. Register the device(s) you want to deploy to
3. Create an App Id for your app. 
   (the "Bundle ID" must exactly match what you have set as "Bundle Identifier" in the Info.plist file)
4. Create a provisioning profile for this App Id (including your devices)

Finally, go to XCode and download the new profile(s).

You can find more information about each of these steps in [Xamarin's documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/#Provisioning_an_iOS_Device_for_Development).

Good luck!